# existing bookmarks seem to be in readonly mode (Vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim oWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("C:\Users\mattia\Documents\Test.dotx")
```

I've tried everything but i can't write in my Bookmarks

```
oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Hello").Range.Text = "Hello Word"
oDoc.Fields.Item(0).Result = "HelloWord"
```

So I've tried to check if ContentControls.Count was > 0 and the property retrive me the correct  number of existing Bookmarks ; but for example using :

```
oDoc.ContentControls.Item("Hello").Range.Text = "Hello Word"
```

I have alway have the same error : "requested member of the collection does not exist"

Comment: Your code works just fine, except from the part `oDoc.Fields.Item(0).Result` which should be `oDoc.Fields.Item(0).Result.Text`

Comment: I have always have the same error ...

Comment: Move your file to another folder like in `C:` or `C:\Users` and check if the bookmark exist.

Comment: "requested member of the collection does not exist"  ... I'm sure that the Tag in my .dotx is : "Hello"

Comment: Use only the first 6 lines of code (.... oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Hello").Range.Text = "Hello Word"). Don't use anything else

Comment: unfortunately it does not work ... If the problem is the interop ?

Comment: if i try : Dim i as integer = oWord.Bookmarks.Count    return me i = 0

Comment: There isn't `oWord.Bookmarks.Count`, only `oDoc.Bookmarks.Count`.